# FileSystemWatcher to email change. Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a powershell script that will look at a file until it gets modified and then **email the change that happened**. So far I have this code + the code that will send the email using **Net.Mail.SmtpClient**

```
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\MatchedLog"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}
$FILE = 'matched.txt'

$FSW = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $TARGETDIR, $FILE - Property@{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FirstName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $FSW Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
}
```

The error I get is:

```
 Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
```

I am not sure exactly why this is happening

Comment: Your `FileSystemWatcher` apparently didn't instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be a typo, but `[IO.NotifyFilters]` doesn't have the definition `FirstName`. You probably mean `FileName`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, it prints the change twice in a row for some reason. I saw many people having the same problem online but I am still trying to find the problem. I also need to get the line that has changed from "matched.txt" and print that instead of "Changed: /path/to/file/matched.txt"

```
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\MatchedLog"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}
$FILE = 'matched.txt'

$FSW = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FSW.Path = $TARGETDIR
$FSW.IncludeSubdirectories = $false

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $FSW "Changed" -Action{
    write-host "Changed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
}
```